# ClusterJ removes schema after failure to initialize domain type handler

Tags: java, mysql, cluster-computing, mysql-cluster

We have mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.11-winx64 running on Windows 8 64bits.
I use 7.4.11 ClusterJ with Java 1.8 64bits.

When I try to run the same code on Windows 10 64 bits I get following messages in the log:
Jun 29, 2016 12:11:11 PM com.mysql.clusterj.core.SessionFactoryImpl getDomainTypeHandler FINEST: DomainTypeToHandler for entities.IEntity(interface entities.IEntity) returned null

Jun 29, 2016 12:11:11 PM com.mysql.clusterj.core.metadata.DomainTypeHandlerFactoryImpl createDomainTypeHandler INFO: Removing schema entity after failure to initialize domain type handler for class entities.IEntity.

After that my code fails to map Java object to my database table by saying:
Failure getting NdbTable for class entities.IEntity, table entity. Verify that the table is defined with ENGINE=NDB.

What can be wrong here? ClusterJ is using ndbclient.dll. Is it possible that DLL is not compatible with new Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Situation is that code was trying to connect to non existent database. Miss leading logging messages!